# How can I pass include path flags to ocamlc/ocamlopt in my dune project

Tags: ocaml, nix, nixos

I'm using [NixOS](https://nixos.org/) and compiling the [cohttp server example](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-cohttp#basic-server-tutorial) using [dune](https://github.com/ocaml/dune). The example is notable in that it links to two C-libraries: openssl and libev.

**initial attempt**

Here's my shell.nix:

```
with import <nixpkgs> { };

let spec = {
  buildInputs = with ocamlPackages; [
    ocaml
    findlib
    dune

    # ocaml libs (and external library deps)
    cohttp-lwt-unix openssl libev
  ]);
};
in runCommand "dummy" spec ""
```

Here's my dune file:

```
(executable
 (name server_example)
 (libraries cohttp-lwt-unix))
```

And the output of `dune build server_example.exe`

```
...
/nix/store/3xwc1ip20b0p68sxqbjjll0va4pv5hbv-binutils-2.30/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/nix/store/3xwc1ip20b0p68sxqbjjll0va4pv5hbv-binutils-2.30/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
/nix/store/3xwc1ip20b0p68sxqbjjll0va4pv5hbv-binutils-2.30/bin/ld: cannot find -lev
```

Ok, not terribly surprising since these are in non-standard locations in NixOS. I need to add the relevant paths to the ocamlopt commandline invoked by dune, e.g.: `-I ${openssl.out}/lib -I ${libev}/lib`.

Now, openssl includes pkg-config files, but adding pkg-config to my `shell.nix` has no apparent effect.

**second attempt, using configurator**

I used [configurator](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configurator.html) to create a program to add flags from an environment variable to the build flags of my dune executable.

shell.nix

```
with import <nixpkgs> { };

let spec = {
  buildInputs = with ocamlPackages; [
    ocaml
    findlib
    dune
    configurator

    # ocaml libs (and external library deps)
    cohttp-lwt-unix openssl libev
  ]);

  shellHook = ''
    export OCAML_FLAGS="-I ${openssl.out}/lib -I ${libev}/lib"
  '';
};
in runCommand "dummy" spec ""
```

dune

```
(executable
 (name server_example)
 (flags (:standard (:include flags.sexp)))
 (libraries cohttp-lwt-unix))

(rule
 (targets flags.sexp)
 (deps (:discover config/discover.exe))
 (action (run %{discover})))
```

config/dune

```
(executable
 (name discover)
 (libraries dune.configurator))
```

config/discover.ml

```
open Sys
module C = Configurator.V1

let () =
  C.main ~name:"getflags" (fun _c ->
      let libs =
        match getenv_opt "OCAML_FLAGS" with
        | None -> []
        | Some flags -> C.Flags.extract_blank_separated_words flags
      in

      C.Flags.write_sexp "flags.sexp" libs)
```

Compilation now succeeds, but this approach of writing a custom program to take an environment variable and put it into the flags argument seems clunky.

Is there a standard way to accomplish this in dune (adding paths to ocamlopt commandline with `-I`)?

If not, is there an easier way to read an environment variable from within `dune` files?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't [pass flags in directly](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dune-files.html#ocaml-flags)?

Comment: The flags are not static: `${openssl.dev}/lib` expands to `/nix/store/$somehash-openssl-$version/lib` where `$somehash` can change more frequently than the openssl version. I could pass them directly, but it's inelegant and will require continual editing over time.

Comment: Possibly, the way to make this a bit more automatic is to base your shell off `buildDunePackage` instead of `runCommand`. [This section](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/index.html#sec-language-ocaml) of the Nixpkgs Manual introduces that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `stdenv.mkDerivation` or (as suggested by [Robert Hensing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428586/robert-hensing) above) `ocamlPackages.buildDunePackage` instead of `runCommand`. The latter results in an environment that does not include openssl and libev in the `NIX_CFLAGS_COMPILE` or `NIX_LDFLAGS` environment variables. Using `mkDerivation` does result in those variables being populated.

Once those variables are in place, compilation via `dune` succeeds, and the executable is linked to libssl and libev.

Furthermore, explicit inclusion of libev and openssl is unnecessary since they are declared as propagated build inputs of through cohttp-lwt-unix.

shell.nix:

```
with import <nixpkgs> { };

with ocamlPackages;

buildDunePackage {
  pname = "dummy";
  version = "0";
  buildInputs = [
    cohttp-lwt-unix
  ];
}
```